# Rails 4 CRUD Update Successful but not saved to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am experiencing a really weird issue in my rails 4 app. I've created a CRUD operation called FOO. All sections work as one would expect it to, except for the Update operation.

The FOO model has 4 Attributes:

1. title
2. body
3. author
4. status

When I load the Update form, the model is loaded into the form as it should be. The update action returns a "SUCCESS" status if a valid form is submitted, but here is the issue: Only the "Title" attribute is ever updated. All the other attributes remain unchanged. If I Update them one-by-one, they also do not change.

Here is my FooController code:

```
def update
  if @foo.validate( params[ :foo ] )
    @foo.save
    respond_with( @foo, location: root_path )
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I am using the Reform GEM instead of Strong Params:

```
class FooForm < ApplicationForm

    property  :title
    property  :body
    property  :author
    property  :status

end
```

And I'm loading the @foo instance in my controller like this:

```
before_action     :load_form_instance,   only: [ :edit, :update ]

def load_form_instance
  @foo = FooForm.new( Foo.find( params[ :id ]) )
end
```

I have tested overwriting these values from my Rails console and that seems to work just fine.

Does anybody have any idea where things might be going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is my development LOG as per a request below:

```
Started PATCH "/foo/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-04 20:19:10 +0200
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Processing by FooController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yB+BwFSKt62uSQZtY6auHZ4+DbxVdcZZE2VIWzgRAhVX3Hqn7xmdKewcJ39LnSQm0hfkK+7HazGdypyI7noobA==", "foo"=>{"title"=>"This is a test", "body"=>"This is Body 2", "author"=>"Test1", "status"=>"Active"}, "commit"=>"Update Foo", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mFoo Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT  "foo".* FROM "foo" WHERE "foo"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'super_admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/foo
Completed 302 Found in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: try using save with a bang and see if it produces any errors. `@foo.save!`

Comment: @MCBama I have tried that as well. Still the same result.

Comment: cool! show your console development log while hitting for update.. I would like to see the `params` content ...in the console..

Comment: durp. I just noticed that won't work because you have a `validate` check outside of that. So, it appears that the validation is failing. Double check the params that are being passed in and make sure they're what your model is looking for.

Comment: Check if you have permitted the remaining fields inside your controller?

Comment: @R_O_R I have Updated the post with my LOG output

Comment: What's in the params hash?

Comment: @MCBama I have removed all validation rules and also removed the validation clause in my Update method and it still results in the same.

Comment: @ValAsensio See the update above.

Comment: I don't see the hash data above? The thing is that the "COMMIT" is telling us that the database was updated. If it wasn't, we'd see a "ROLLBACK." I'm curious what's in the hash because that data may lead to the answer.

Comment: @ValAsensio I am using their syntax. I think it might just be a difference in naming of my Objects.

Comment: We need to see what is in params[ :foo ].

Comment: The before action is loading a `FooForm` for edit, but don't you need to load `@foo` with the view data (params) somewhere?  Where is that happening?

Comment: I have managed to find the culprit. It seems that the FriendlyID gem I have installed was preventing some field from updating. I have no idea why this is.